# How can I mount a 55" TV on a wall with 5/16" paneling?

Tags: walls, wood, mounting, studs, television

We have a 55" OLED TV 55 C9 and its wall bracket go together in the box. However I need to mount it on the wood paneling wall which is 1 cm thick and there is a distance around 2 inches space distance between this wood panel and the concrete wall.

Based on my research on internet the thickness of the wood panel is in range of sufficiency.

But I really don't know what type of screws, stud and how is the right order to mount it? I need an explanation with pictures or video to make sure I understand how to install it correctly and safely because I am not very familiar with the steps.

Below is set of pictures of my setup and items as well as the instruction guide for wall installation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

My biggest concern is since I can access only the front side of the panel then I could not place bolts with nuts to hold back the system and prevent it from pulling out by the heavy weight of the bracket and the TV.
They do use screws but it is for the walls with expansion anchor and long, big screws so I guess it can support very heavy weight.
What would be the good solution for my setup ? Thank you !

Comment: _"there is a distance around 2 inches space distance between this wood panel and the concrete wall."_   Then you have 2 inch thick studs you should be able to find and use.  They usually mount outlets to studs so you should be able to find them easily.

Answer (score 2):

Your paneling appears to be nominally 3/8", or about 5/16" actual. That's not sufficient to hold lag screws with confidence, in my opinion.

Assuming that the paneling is well fastened to the framing, hollow wall anchors should do nicely. Your TV isn't crazy heavy and the mount keeps it close to the wall, so there isn't an extraordinary amount of force on the fasteners.

I suggest mollies, or similar, because they don't require oversized holes like togglers do. They hold position much better than conventional winged toggle bolts.

[image]

Of course, as was pointed out in a comment, you probably have framing *somewhere*. You could also find that and mount to it with the lag screws.

<sub>I have the 65" E8. It's astoundingly good. True blacks are a game changer. I can't imagine TV makers improving on it except for the smoothing software, which sometimes needs a tweak.</sub>

Comment: Hi Isherwood, yes, tk you, I love my TV display a lot as well, (also agree with you about the software) that's why I really want to secure it on the frame. So are you suggesting me to use > 2 inches mollies screw to position the frame to the wood and the wall through the space ? (Yes the paneling is well fastened to the framing, but I have to position it in the marked area in my picture only)

Comment: Mollies are for hollow walls. Use those which are designed for your combined paneling and bracket thickness.

Comment: @isherwood:  So the mollies will go through the TV bracket holes and then wooden paneling and then space-between-panelling-and-wall and then to the wall is it ? Then it must be pretty long I guess. If it is very short and only stick to the wooden paneling and the TV bracket, then I think it might not be strong enough for that weight ?

Comment: No. As my answer states, hollow wall anchors will work, with them fastened to _the paneling alone_. I have not suggested mounting to the wall _behind_ the void. That doesn't usually work very well.

Answer (score 1):

I did not have enough confident to hang the TV on the wooden paneling alone, so I have cut a square hole big enough for the bracket and use 8mm drill bit to drill hole for the bolt (6 pieces) to hang the bracket to the wall and now the TV can sit nicely on that.

Comment: Fair enough, but you didn't need confidence. You needed _evidence_. By attempting the mount as suggested, then doing a test by hanging your weight on it, you'd _know_ whether it would hold a TV or not. I'd have done that before cutting up my wall, but that's just me.

Comment: Presumably you have more confidence in using fasteners in concrete .... would be nice if you gave a little more detail on how you did that.